# PrimeFaces inputSwitch not correctly shown if it is in a hidden div

Tags: javascript, css, primefaces

I'm using an `InputSwitch` inside a `<div>` that is shown on a button press.

The `InputSwitch` is not rendered correctly when the `<div>` is shown - it appears as just a thin gray box. If the `InputSwitch` is placed outside of the hidden `<div>` it's fine, so it definitely seems to be related to being inside the hidden `<div>`.

Is there some sort of initialization I should do when it is shown? My example code is as follows

```
This is rendered correctly
<p:inputSwitch value="#{bean.booleanValue}"/>

<div style="display:none" class="hidden-test">
    This is not rendered correctly after showing the div
    <p:inputSwitch value="#{bean.booleanValue}"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Components often dynamically determine their size when rendered. Sometimes in javascript, sometimes in css..If a parent is hidden, their calculated size can  then sometimes end up being 0 (depending on how it is calculated or what css is used). Possible solutiuons:

- You can try to e.g. give it an explicit width in a style or via a styleClass.
- A more complex solution is to bind an 'onShow' event on the paren container en try to call the [init function of the inputSwitch](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/inputswitch/inputswitch.js)

Comment: I thought the PrimeFaces team overcame this issue in 5.2. See also Issue 'Rewrite Hidden Container Support' https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7649

Comment: Hidden jsf containers, not plain html ones.(so hidden tab in tabview, accordion panel, panel etc)

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje, I didn't get it. So I guess I should turn my plain html tabs into jsf tabs.

Comment: As far as I know, they solved it for hidden primefaces containers only. And you have this problem with a plain jquery  or custom tabview, then you can also use my second suggestion

Comment: The width fixed the issue where it wasn't showing, but the click handlers don't seem to be bound. Any sample of calling init? Doing something like `PF("widget").init()` throws a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` error.

Comment: Weird, would not expect the adding of the clickhandlers to be related to the display...